# How to send datetime with route in Blazor

Tags: c#, routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im trying to create a route for one of my Blazor webpages that sends a date time. According to the documentation its supported but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. Heres how I am doing it.

Where Im trying to go:

```
@page "/routeTest/{number:int}/{date:datetime}"

@code {       
    [Parameter] public int number { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

How I am attempting to navigate there

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("routeTest/"+numberToSend+"/"+dateToSend);
```

Its navigating me to

```
https://localhost:44383/routeTest/123/12/11/2019%204:36:26%20PM
```

Which while technically correct doesn't work and I'm fairly certain its the dateTime objects fault. How am I suppose to be able to correctly send a dateTime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your in your language dates use the slash separator, which makes Blazor think you're trying to access a different route.

Whenever sending dates as a URL parameter they need to be in invariant culture and use dashes.

```cs
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("routeTest/"+numberToSend+"/"+dateToSend.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

For reference, see the warning in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraints)

Answer (score 4):

As you've identified, the DateTime in the URL is affecting the routing due to the slashes.

Send the `DateTime` in ISO8601 format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

You could use:

```
dateToSend.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

where the format specifier `s` is known as the [Sortable date/time pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier)

Or

```
dateToSend.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Use `InvariantCulture` since the [Blazor routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) page states:

> Route constraints that verify the URL and are converted to a CLR type
> (such as `int` or `DateTime`) always use the invariant culture. These
> constraints assume that the URL is non-localizable.

Answer (score 3):

This can solve your issue:

```
@code{
    int numberToSend = 123;
    string dateToSend = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    private void Naviagte()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("routeTest/" + numberToSend + "/" + dateToSend);
    }

}
```